# Mostrar uma div e esconder outra no Hover

Tags: jquery

Tenho 3 divs que mostram 3 produtos:

```
<div class="produtosDestaqueBoxItem">
    <div class="produtosDestaqueBoxItemCentralizar">
        <img src="imagens/produto1 (1).jpg" height="131" width="120" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="produtosDestaqueBoxItem">
    <div class="produtosDestaqueBoxItemCentralizar">
        <img src="imagens/produto1 (2).jpg" height="131" width="120" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="produtosDestaqueBoxItem">
    <div class="produtosDestaqueBoxItemCentralizar">
        <img src="imagens/produto1 (3).jpg" height="131" width="120" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

E uma div com `display:none` que aparece só quando passa o mouse em cima da div `produtosDestaqueBoxItem`.

```
<div style="display:none" class="produtoDestaqueBox">teste</div>
```

Fiz isso com Jquery:

```
$(".produtosDestaqueBoxItem").hover(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.produtoDestaqueBox').show();
});
```

Porém, isso funciona apenas no primeiro item. Teria que usar INDEX, ELEMENT?

Exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: As divs `. produtosDestaqueBoxItem` e `. produtoDestaqueBox` são irmãs?

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer, é algo semelhante a isso: http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/p97BN/ ??

Comment: isso mesmo @DiegoVieira

Comment: Isso resolve seu problema? pois pode fazer de mais de uma forma, sem mesmo utilizar jquery

Comment: Quase. No hover, ele aplica a classe que informei, mas quando está fora, ele volta ao normal

Comment: @bfavaretto não. A div `produtosDestaqueBoxItem` tem 3 iguais, a `produtoDestaqueBox` aparece somente no hover

Comment: Mas qual é a relação entre elas no HTML?

Comment: São 3 divs `produtosDestaqueBoxItemCentralizar`. Quando eu passo o mouse em cima de uma delas, o `produtoDestaqueBox` deixa de ser `display:none` e fica `display:block`, ele substitui a div. O Jquery que usei funcionou apenas no primeiro item.

Comment: Então tem um único `produtoDestaqueBox` para os 3 produtos?

Comment: @FelipeStoker http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/p97BN/1/

Comment: Basicamente o que eu estou tentando entender é se o seu HTML é o que está na resposta do Jader ou se é outra coisa. Por favor [sempre poste o HTML necessário para que os outros possam reproduzir o problema](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FelipeStoker essa é meu último palpite, não entendi muito o que você deseja. http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/p97BN/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta ocultando o elemento que esta disparando o hover...

acho que deve ser algo assim:

**jquery:**

```
$( ".produtosDestaqueBoxItem" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).children(".produtosDestaqueBoxItemCentralizar").hide();
    $( this ).children(".produtoDestaqueBox").fadeIn();
  },
  function() {
    $( this ).children(".produtosDestaqueBoxItemCentralizar").show();
    $( this ).children(".produtoDestaqueBox").fadeOut();
  }
);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="produtosDestaqueBoxItem">
    <div class="produtosDestaqueBoxItemCentralizar">
        <img src="imagens/produto1 (1).jpg" height="131" width="120" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div style="display:none" class="produtoDestaqueBox">teste</div>
</div>
```

obs.: Se quiser, `style="display:none"` pode ser incorporado na classe `.produtoDestaqueBox`

Comment: Show de bola, só que ele não esconde a div `produtosDestaqueBoxItem` e mostra a div `produtoDestaqueBox` no lugar dela.

Comment: acabo de editar, mas como eu disse, você não pode ocultar o elemento que dispara o hover, pois assim vai imediatamente disparar o "mouseout", e anular a ação, ao invez disso, oculte todo o restante do conteúdo, mantendo o div que esta disparando o hover visível.

Comment: Entendi @Jader, muito obrigado, funcionou! :P

Comment: Só uma outra dúvida @Jader, eu poderia ter usado o `find` no lugar do `children`?

Comment: Sim funciona do mesmo jeito, a diferença é que o find procura até dentro dos filhos sem limite de níveis, e o children apenas nos filhos do elemento pai.